# Python integer refusing to increment (+=) during debug

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am debugging a complicated Python program (VSCode Python debugger) and there is a very baffling behavior that I am noticing:

```
> type(self.i)
<class 'int'>
> self.i
1
> self.i+1
2
> self.i += 1
None
> self.i
1
> self.i = self.i + 1
None
> self.i
1
```

The variable `self.i` just refuses altogether to increment. I have highlighted a debugging session but even without any breakpoint, if the execution is inside a debug session, a loop that should take 5 iterations takes a random, longer, number of iterations. This behavior happens:

- only when some external code is modified in a specific way
- only when using the debugger. Just running the script via python makes the problem go away

The context is that we are inside a `__next__` method of an iterator, the snippet is

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.i < self.num_samples:
        i = self.i
        self.i += 1 # <- here is a breakpoint
        ....
```

The code that toggles the behavior is inside a for loop using an instance of said iterator. There should really be no relation between it and what happens inside the iterator, but when a computationally expensive line that involves pytorch backpropagation is decommented the problem happens.

This is puzzling me because it is so mysterious. I can't understand why a variable should refuse to increment, whether there is a bug, and if so where it is (in the VSCode debugger, in my code, in Python, in PyTorch, ...?). So I would be very grateful if someone could shed a bit of light on  the issue

EDIT:

The class where this happens is called `SpectraDataLoader` and is an iterator. The only references to i are in `__iter__` and `__next__` (shown before):

```
def __iter__(self):
    ...
    self.i = 0
    ...
    return self
```

Comment: Well, it all depends on what `self` is and what it does to `i`. And that code is not available here.

Comment: What are `type(self).i` and `type(type(self).i)`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams doing that brings about an error but I explained the context a bit more in the question

Comment: Can you file a bug at github.com/microsoft/ptvsd ?